# How do I run a .exe but stay in the same command window (not open a new one)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have searched for many weeks to solve my problem and can't find a good way of doing it that works on every machine I may need to use.

I know START command opens a new window to do the .exe, but I want to stay in the same window and run the .exe

(because I want my batch file to continue ONLY WHEN THE .EXE has finished running)

I have found that on some computers when I .exe it opens a new window and other computers is stays in the same window which makes me think my code is fine but there is a setting somewhere on the computers that is different.

Can you help? What are my options? The .exe I am running is NASTRAN which is an engineering solver that runs in command window.

Comment: Did you try to 'start' by '/B' option?

Comment: Yes I tried that and it still opens a new window to do the .exe and goes to the next line in the original command window.

Comment: Why are you using `START` command in first place? If you want sequential execution of the .EXE file in the original window just remove the `START` command!

Comment: that didn't work mate, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have a different variant of the .exe on some machines which is called only there, and spawns a separate window, for reasons I cannot know. Search for the .exe file on all machines and compare.

Also, post your batch file code so we can exactly see how you start the .exe.

Comment: Thanks for helping me in chat mate... there were two versions of the .exe, one spawned a new window, one stayed in the current window, I have changed the batch to call the latter :) solved!!

Answer (score 40):

To wait for the command to terminate you should use the `WAIT` flag:

```
start /WAIT c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe
```

You could start an application without creating a new window using the `B` flag:

```
start /WAIT /B "c:/windows/system32/cmd.exe"
```

You should also try reading the help text for the start command:

```
start /?
```

Comment: start /B and start /WAIT do not work. It still opens a new cmd window to execute the .exe, and moves on to the next line in the original window.

Comment: @OliverBennett - What OS are you running? Have you tried combining the both switches `start /B /WAIT command`? Can you post your complete commandline?

Comment: I had the same problem trying to run a .NET "ClickOnce" application.  I would guess that using this technique will work for `.exe` files but not `.Application` files.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `cmd /k example.exe`

Comment: It works, but kills your history and adds a running shell to the stack. This should probly be avoided for common applications.

Answer (score 4):

You could consider *not using start* at all. Simply start the executable directly.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using call  in the batch file. it runs the exe in the same window. as the batch file. The next statement in the batch file is executed after this exe is finished running

Comment: `call` doesn't affect the opening of a window for exe files at all

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this you have to run an executable *from the directory where it is located*, and also have to *avoid the use of "start" command*.

For example:

```
cd C:\MyDirectory\
MyApplication.exe -Parameter1 -ParameterN
```

Comment: Both claims are wrong. A normal exe can be started from anywhere. And like the answers already explained, `Start` can be used with `/B` and for some exe's it's required

Comment: "Start" with "/B" option doesn't work properly in some cases... It either still runs an executable in a new window, or the log output in the current window appears to be corrupted.
It may depend on the particular application and on the OS version...

Probably, running an executable from its directory also would not work in some specific cases, but it is always working properly with any CLI applications i have tested. So, it is the most handy way.

Comment: And if application requires some specific options provided by "Start", then it will be already another question: "How do I run a .exe _with Start command_ but stay in the same command window (not open a new one)?"

Answer (score 0):

I achieved showing output of my executable (no aforementioned solutions worked for me) in the same CMD window only via rights escalation script (it will launch your `.bat`/`.cmd` file as admin):

```
if _%1_==_payload_  goto :payload

:getadmin
    echo %~nx0: elevating self
    set vbs=%temp%\getadmin.vbs
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)                >> "%vbs%"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "payload %~sdp0 %*", "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbs%"
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
goto :eof

:payload

<<<start writing your commands from here. E.g.:
"C:\my program\launcher.exe" argument1>>>

pause
```

P.S. Don't forget to remove `<<<` and `>>>` from script.